# TextBox UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged - does it really affect performance?

Tags: wpf, performance, binding, updatesourcetrigger

The MSDN documentation states:

> Bindings that are TwoWay or
>   OneWayToSource listen for changes in
>   the target property and propagate them
>   back to the source. This is known as
>   updating the source. Usually, these
>   updates happen whenever the target
>   property changes. This is fine for
>   check boxes and other simple controls,
>   but it is usually not appropriate for
>   text fields. **Updating after every
>   keystroke can diminish performance** and
>   it denies the user the usual
>   opportunity to backspace and fix
>   typing errors before committing to the
>   new value. Therefore, the default
>   UpdateSourceTrigger value of the Text
>   property is LostFocus and not
>   PropertyChanged.

I understand that in a situation where the update is going directly to a database, or across a network, or if it's an extremely large amount of data, that it could indeed diminish performance to use UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged on TextBoxes.

But if it is just updating a simple DependencyProperty, or a property of an Entity Framework object (prior to committing), would the performance hit not be negligible?

Just wondering, because I am creating a WPF app which tracks the state of the object being edited and optimizes the Save button appearance depending on whether changes have been made. I thought the easiest way to determine changes would be to catch the relevant SourceUpdated occurences as appropriate. It works optimally when UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged for the textboxes, as the user gets instant feedback that there are "saveable" changes.

Comment: I think the best way to answer that is to profile your application.

Comment: Well using my eyes alone to "visually" profile it, there certainly seems to be no performance hit. I guess I was wondering whether it might seem to be fine at first, but can actually cause issues in certain situations I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're warned about performance degradation is that for the most part, if you need to have the source property updated on every keystroke, it's because you need something  to happen when the property's value changes.  After all, if you didn't need that "something" to happen, you wouldn't really care when the property got updated, so long as it did eventually.

The real impact on performance depends entirely on what that "something" is.  And that's totally dependent on your application.  If that "something" is formatting and displaying the value in another `TextBlock`, doing it on every keystroke probably won't be noticeable.  If it's filtering a 10,000-row `DataTable` and refreshing a `DataGrid` bound to it, it probably will.

So how do you tell?  Well, there are two ways:

1) Understand your application.  If you know what the application is doing when you update the source property, you can predict whether or not doing it on every keystroke is going to be a problem.  When you say "I guess I was wondering whether it might seem to be fine at first, but can actually cause issues in certain situations I'm not aware of," what you're really saying is, "What happens if I don't know what my application is doing when the user presses a key?"

2) If you don't know what your application is doing when the user presses a key, profile it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is suitable for your application and you don't notice a significant degradation in performance, then there is no problem setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to be `PropertyChanged`. In fact, if you're using an MVVM framework such as [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), then it will set this as the default setting for all TextBoxes.